# Visual Studio 2012 debug window distorted

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012

After I installed the latest patch of visual studio 2012, my debug window got distorted as shown in picture.
[image: debug window distortion]

Anyone knows any fixes? Thanks a lot

Comment: it looks as if the font is too big. did you magnify somehow or change the font size?

Comment: Yea, it fixed the problem. I can't believe I thought about it! Apparent it my font size, 16, was working before but not after the patch. Thank you

Comment: How did you set everything including the debug windows to have a dark background? Is this color theme available online or did you make it yourself? Thanks.

Comment: It's a setting in VS2012. No third party stuff going on there.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I somehow thought the background was light just like in VS2010. When I compiled a project now, it's all dark in mine too. Good thing MS did it right this time.